# node env value does not get changed with process manager command

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am writing `NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app` to run the node environment into production mode. But somehow when I extract the value with `app.get('env')` it gives me development value only. So what should be inserted to run node environment into production mode ?

Comment: are you deleting the process then starting that app right?

Comment: what I am doing is `pm2 stop app` and then `NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app`

Comment: that's where you're doing wrong. You have to do `pm2 delete app` then start it

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Can you put it as an answer so that future users can benefit from it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default we want that PM2 doesn’t change process environment while restarting or reloading. So, In order to change the ENV value of a process just stopping and starting won't work.

You have to either `DELETE` the process and start again(which I mainly do because when I change envs there are some major changes happening inside, so this method works for me)

```
pm2 delete app
NODE_ENV=prod pm2 start app
```

Or, From the [Doc](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/) "If you want to update them [While restarting/reloading a process], you must use `--update-env`":

> You want to inject a new environment variable to a process (for
>   example DEBUG): Use `DEBUG=* pm2 reload myapp --update-env`